# Get new values of textbox from a listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I'm generating a listview with textboxes inside. The textboxes values comes from a database. My issue comes when I want to retrieve the new values of the textboxes.
Here's what I do on click of the save button.

```
 For Each item In mylistview.Items
     Dim tbLgName As TextBox = CType(item.FindControl("tbLgName"), TextBox)
     // code to encode into db ...    
 Next
```

The thing is it get the textbox but with the old values (coming from the db), How can I get the new value?

Thanx

Comment: Perhaps because you're rebinding the ListView on each and every postback from Page_Load instead of checking for `Not Page.IsPostBack`.

Comment: Nope the problem doesn't comes from a post back...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found that it was because I had added an OnLoad to my UpdatePanel that was binding this ListView.  It was easy to fix because I was not using that way anymore and just removed it.  For others it may not be as easy to fix, but may help figure out what is causing it.

(Yes, I realize how old this post is, but someone else may benefit down the road)